# Accessing Google+ (Ruby) API in public mode

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

I want to do the equivalent of e.g. [this API explorer call](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=people.listByActivity&activityId=z12nspyxxufislit423eex442zqpdtqnk&collection=plusoners&fields=items/id,nextPageToken) using the [google ruby API client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/).

That ought to be simply:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'httpadapter/adapters/net_http'

@client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :key => MY_SIMPLE_API_SERVER_KEY,
  :host => 'www.googleapis.com',
  :http_adapter => HTTPAdapter::NetHTTPAdapter.new, 
  :pretty_print => false
)
@plus = @client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')

status, headers, body = @client.execute(
  @plus.people.list_by_activity,
  'activityId' => 'z12nspyxxufislit423eex442zqpdtqnk',
  'collection' => 'plusoners',
  'maxResults' => '100',
  'authenticated' => 'false'
)
public_activity = JSON.parse(body[0])
```

However, that `execute` call results in `ArgumentError: Missing access token.`

I *don't* want to log users in; I only want to access *public* data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I poked around in the client code and found a couple of options.

First, you can create an API client that will make all requests without an access token. The constructor is probably a bit more aggressive than it should be about specifying a default. To work around this you can nil out the authentication method after you've created the client. Your code will look like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'httpadapter/adapters/net_http'

@client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :key => 'SOME_KEY',
  :host => 'www.googleapis.com',
  :http_adapter => HTTPAdapter::NetHTTPAdapter.new, 
  :pretty_print => false
)
@client.authorization = nil

@plus = @client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')

status, headers, body = @client.execute(
  @plus.people.list_by_activity,
  'activityId' => 'z12nspyxxufislit423eex442zqpdtqnk',
  'collection' => 'plusoners',
  'maxResults' => '100'
)
public_activity = JSON.parse(body[0])
```

Alternatively, you can override the authentication method on a per-request basis. You were pretty close to this one! You had the correct option, you just need to pass it in as the final argument like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'httpadapter/adapters/net_http'

@client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :key => 'SOME_KEY',
  :host => 'www.googleapis.com',
  :http_adapter => HTTPAdapter::NetHTTPAdapter.new, 
  :pretty_print => false
)
@plus = @client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')

status, headers, body = @client.execute(
  @plus.people.list_by_activity,
  {'activityId' => 'z12nspyxxufislit423eex442zqpdtqnk',
  'collection' => 'plusoners',
  'maxResults' => '100'}, '', [], {:authenticated => false}
)
puts status
puts body
public_activity = JSON.parse(body[0])
```

Thanks to [Allen](https://plus.google.com/101852559274654726533) for bringing this one to my attention on Google+ :)

Comment: `@client.authorization = nil` worked perfectly for my needs. I would note though that `execute` returns a single `Google::APIClient::Result` value, not a 3-value array, so the `status, headers, body = ` bit is wrong (`response.status`, `response.headers`, and `response.body` do work though). I'll file a bug for that.

Comment: @Sai: Jenny's answer is from an older alpha version of the client. The current version returns a `Result` object, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks different than the sample ruby code at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/listByActivity#examples is the extra field 'authenticated' => 'false'.

Comment: Same result without specifying `authenticated`.